# IntelliJ GUI designer missing mnemonic

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've just migrated from Eclipse to JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA and I find it very annoying when it comes to using designer. When I create a new GUI form the designer works fine for some time. Then suddenly after switching to other class or after closing and reopening IntelliJ it shows me XML code only and I have no option to switch to designer mode. This time I have form with three buttons and IntelliJ shows me XML with three notifications at the top "missing mnemonic: name_of_a_button" despite that I didn't use any and never wanted to. By the way even if it works fine I don't have that switch at the bottom to toggle between designer and text mode. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two options:
(1) Disabling this particular inspection by clicking the icon at the right of the message;
(2) Going to the button's Component Properties panel, "Text" property,clicking on the lamp icon and providing a mnemonic for the text. (image berllow)
[image]

Comment: I don't have an option to toggle to designer mode so I can't go to the properties panel

Comment: If you are seeing the .form file as a XML text instead of design view, you can close the file, locate in the navigation view, and double-click it, or select and press F4.